# WP_Query returns no results

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-query

I'm using wp_query to create a custom query that retrieves search results but it is returning 0 results.  Here is the code:

```
$query = 's=the&posts_per_page=5&paged=1';
$custom_query = new WP_Query();
$custom_query->query($query);

if( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();
                    $this->get_article();
        endwhile;
}
else
        $this->posts_404();
```

When I search for the word 'the' through the search box on the UI, it returns 37 hits, but searching for the word 'the' with my custom query returns 0.  So, I suspect there must be a problem with my query.

Result: of `print_r($Custom_query)`:

```
WP_Query Object ( 
 [query_vars] => Array 
  ( [s] => the 
    [posts_per_page] => 5 
    [paged] => 1 
    [error] => 
    [m] => 0 
    [p] => 0 
    [post_parent] => 
    [subpost] => 
    [subpost_id] => 
    [attachment] => 
    [attachment_id] => 0 
    [name] => 
    [static] => 
    [pagename] => 
    [page_id] => 0 
    [second] => [minute] => [hour] => [day] => 0 [monthnum] => 0 [year] => 0 
    [w] => 0 
    [category_name] => [tag] => [cat] => [tag_id] => [author_name] => [feed] => [tb] => [comments_popup] => [meta_key] => [meta_value] => [preview] => [sentence] => [fields] => 
    [category__in] => Array ( ) 
    [category__not_in] => Array ( ) 
    [category__and] => Array ( ) [post__in] => Array ( ) [post__not_in] => Array ( ) [tag__in] => Array ( ) [tag__not_in] => Array ( ) [tag__and] => Array ( ) [tag_slug__in] => Array ( ) [tag_slug__and] => Array ( ) 
[ignore_sticky_posts] => [suppress_filters] => 
[cache_results] => 1 
[update_post_term_cache] => 1
[update_post_meta_cache] => 1 
[post_type] => any [nopaging] => 
[comments_per_page] => 50 [no_found_rows] => 
[search_terms] => Array ( [0] => the ) [order] => DESC ) 
[tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object ( [queries] => Array ( ) [relation] => AND )    
[meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object ( [queries] => Array ( ) [relation] => )    
[post_count] => 0 
[current_post] => -1 
[in_the_loop] => 
[comment_count] => 0 
[current_comment] => -1 
[found_posts] => 0 
[max_num_pages] => 0 
[max_num_comment_pages] => 0 
[is_single] => [is_preview] => [is_page] => [is_archive] => [is_date] => [is_year] => [is_month] => [is_day] => [is_time] => [is_author] => [is_category] => [is_tag] => [is_tax] => 
[is_search] => 1 
[is_feed] => [is_comment_feed] => [is_trackback] => [is_home] => [is_404] => [is_comments_popup] => [is_paged] => [is_admin] => [is_attachment] => [is_singular] => [is_robots] => [is_posts_page] => [is_post_type_archive] => 
[query_vars_hash] => 16a0222409543c8384496148e5b60565 
[query_vars_changed] => [thumbnails_cached] => 
[query] => Array ( [s] => the [posts_per_page] => 5 [paged] => 1 ) [request] => SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=2 [posts] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: Try it with only the `s=the`.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the query alone, though the preferred method is to pass an array of arguments rather than a query string, but that wouldn't change the results. without seeing the context of where this is used it's difficult to say where the error may be. what happens if you put the query directly in a template file and `print_r($custom_query);`?

Comment: Tried just s=the but no cigar. I've added the result of the print_r to the post (tried to format it as best I could!)

Comment: It is obvious why it fails: `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=2` That is never going to return anything. Now to work out why the query looks like that...

Comment: Where exactly are you putting this code? Also, for formatting, try `echo '<pre>'; print_r($custom_query); echo '</pre>';`.

Comment: Lol, yeah `where 1=2` isn't gonna have any results! I'm working within the pagelines framework.  I'm creating a custom section (http://www.pagelines.com/docs/custom-sections).  I've added the section to my search template and this is the result.  Looks like there's some kind of conflict with the framework in that case.

Comment: Apparently `where 1 = 2` will retrieve the schema of a table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149142/where-1-1-statement#comment-10007395

Comment: Little dynamo, did you ever figure out what is happening here?

Answer (score 3):

Lets take the nicer form of what you have as posted in another answer

```
$args = array(
    's' => 'the',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => 1
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I strongly recommend you use WP_Query with an argument array and pass in via the constructor like this.

Lets look at your arguments closer.

```
'paged' => 1
```

Paged is the page number to show.

This says, show page 2. You're dealing with computers, and the first number is ***0***, not ***1***.

Change to:

```
'paged' => 0
```

You also missed out a call to `wp_reset_postdata();` to clean up after yourself, and you never specified the post type, post status, and wether the search box is doing a standard search or a search modified by a plugin

Comment: Hi Tom, While agree with using an args array over the method posted by the OP, I think your theory on the paged parameter is incorrect.

'paged' => 1 should show the first page in a set of paginated result (there's no need to include it unless pagination is being used).

I think this example of setting the paged parameter from the codex should back up what I'm saying:

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

If paged isn't set, set it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **&post_type=any** to your query

```
$query = 's=the&posts_per_page=5&paged=1&post_type=any';
```

Comment: Just tried that but same result I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and then add your Loop -

```
$args = array(
    's' => 'the',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => 1
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

You need to pass the arguments when you are initiating the Query, otherwish you are just setting up a blank query, and then using `$custom_query->query($args);` is only telling the query what arguments to use, it's not actually running the query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no difference :(

Comment: Ok, so it looks like `[request]` is the issue. Typically a bad query is bacuase of bad query vars, but those are fine. It's possibly due to the location of the query in your code - where exactly is it located?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, both as you have it written and in a couple of shorthand versions (`New WP_Query($query)` and `New Wp_Query('s=the')`), which makes sense. Those should be equivalent. There has to be something in a plugin or your theme that is causing this. Look for code that manipulates WP_Query-- [`posts_where`, `posts_clauses`, `pre_get_posts`, etc.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters) I don't think this is really a WP_Query issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a plugin or something getting in the way. Try adding suppress_filters=true to your query args to see if that fixes it. If works, check what plugin/theme is messing with your query.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried adding `suppress_filters=true` but it didn't work.  It actually came through empty in the `print_r` i.e. `[query] => Array ( [s] => the [posts_per_page] => 5 [paged] => 1 [post_type] => any [suppress_filters] => )`

Comment: Try suppress_filters=1 ?

Comment: Same result :(  Seems like there's something else going on.  I'm going to try `query_posts` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Don't do that! :P

Comment: Try deactivating all your plugins and test. And then activate one by one until you find the culprit.